# Keytool EC KeyPairGenerator not available

Tags: java, keytool

When I use **keytool** to generate a key with ECC, I get this **error**:

> Error keytool: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC KeyPairGenerator not available

Then syntax used to generate a key is:

```
keytool -genkey -alias testing -keyalg EC -keysize 256 -keystore try.jks -dname "CN=localhost,OU=dep,O=lks,L=ny,ST=ny,C=USA"
```

I have this Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_60"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b16)                            
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b16, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by reading the following [article](http://armoredbarista.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-use-ecc-with-openjdk.html#!/2013/10/how-to-use-ecc-with-openjdk.html) (linked by the user @QuakeCore). If someone has the same issue, he/she can solve by following my steps:

1. Download [Java Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (tar.gz);
2. Copy the file `jdk1.8.0_*/jre/lib/amd64/libsunec.so` from extracted folder to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libsunec.so`;
3. Use the syntax written in my original question to generate the key.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with `pepk (Play Encrypt Private Key)` on Ubuntu 16.04.

I solved this with a solution close to CipherX's answer:

1. Download [Java Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (tar.gz)
2. Extract the files
3. Instead of launching `java` installed on the sytem, launch `java` from the extracted files:

```
~/Downloads/android/jdk-9.0.1/bin/java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=acme.keystore \
--alias=acme --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=eb…
```

And the `Error: EC KeyPairGenerator not available` error disappeared.

Comment: This is the only google result when searching for "pepk" and the error message.  You might move it to its own question and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that your EC security provider is missing, please do the following to add it:

- Edit the file "jdk1.8.0_65\lib\security\java.security"
- Search for "List of providers and their preference order"
- Add "security.provider.[Last security provider id +1]=sun.security.ec.SunEC" to the list of security providers.

see this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC) for more details about the sunEC security provider.

Comment: I have already this provider on java.security (the third element) -> http://imgur.com/LdQt5jt

Comment: I guess you don't have the sunec.jar in your jdk/lib/ext folder, please try to download it and add It there.

Comment: Sorry @QuakeCore, but I have this library too -> http://imgur.com/a/yETIL
The stranger thing is that if I use RSA I can generate the key, but with ECC, nope.

Comment: Take a look at this http://armoredbarista.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-use-ecc-with-openjdk.html#!/2013/10/how-to-use-ecc-with-openjdk.html

Comment: keytool seems entirely broken since a long time (at least for MacOS releases). I tested both Java8, 11, and 14 and both with OpenJDK and OracleJDK. I always get 
keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: *** KeyGenerator not available
No matter what I try for "-keyalg" - I tried with RSA, EC, ECDSA, etc.
Also there is no file "lib\security\java.security" in the MacOS version or Java (yes, I looked under Contents/Home).