# keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC KeyPairGenerator not available

Tags: java, linux, security, arm, keytool

I tried to execute command on arm device with **jre1.8**:

```
/java/bin/keytool -genkeypair -alias MyServerPair -keyalg EC -keysize 256 -keypass changeit -validity 365 -storetype JKS -keystore /keystoreDir -storepass changeit
```

I am getting error :

> keytool error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: EC KeyPairGenerator not available

I followed steps provided here: [Keytool EC KeyPairGenerator not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40957280/keytool-ec-keypairgenerator-not-available)

But unable to solve my issue.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle JRE?

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle's JRE